# Can I change my data split after making a model?

Tags: dataset

I created a model but realized I incorrectly split the data between training and test sets so my prediction accuracy is low. Is it unethical to redo my modelling attempt over from the start and redoing my data split?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand "unethical" correctly. You can overfit the model to some split if you search for the best split looking at target metric. For example, if you have 20% in training set and 80% in testing set, there's no problems to redo modelling with another split (60/40 or 80/20)

Answer (score 0):

Did you randomize your dataset correctly first?

If you apply a reliable random function(like the one from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)), you shouldn't worry about whether it is due to a wrong split or not.

In case of doubt, you can change the random_state or seed in order to have a different random distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In general your model training phase should not 'see' dev/test data. This means that every test you do on it needs to be data 'unseen' by your model.

Models work with data, so if your data is compromised since the beginning, your predictions will be harmed for sure.